# How can I intercept and modify any attempt to change the title in a JavaFX Scene?

Tags: java, string, window, javafx-8

With Swing, I had a class like this:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final String APP_NAME = "My App";

    // ...

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
         super.setTitle(newTitle == null || newTitle.isEmpty() ? APP_NAME : newTitle + " - " + APP_NAME);
    }
}
```

This would perform **the behavior I want: guarantee the title always contains the app name, like `"Editing - My App"`, or if set to `null` or `""`, simply `"My App"`.**

I attempted to replicate this behavior in JavaFX, but [`Stage#setTitle` is `final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-). So, I tried attaching a custom `ChangeListener<String>` to the `#titleProperty()` of the Scene (because `Scene#setTitle(String)` is `final`), but quickly fell short when I couldn't find a way to intercept and change the value before it appeared on the window, at least not without infinite recursion.

**How do I intercept any attempts to change the title, modify such attempts, and then pass that value along to be the title in a JavaFX Scene?**

Here's what I tried in JavaFX:

```
public static class MyWindow extends Stage {
    public static final String APP_NAME = "My App";

    /** this is what I'll pass a stage to if I can't or don't wish to make my own */
    public static void setupStage(Stage stage) {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        stage.setTitle(APP_NAME);
        stage.titleProperty().addListener(new MyTitleChangeListener(APP_NAME));
    }

    public MyWindow() {
        super();
        setupStage(this);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String newTitle) { // <<< ERROR OCCURS <<< I cannot do this because setTitle is final
         super.setTitle(newTitle == null || newTitle.isEmpty() ? APP_NAME : newTitle + " - " + APP_NAME);
    }

    // ...

    private static class MyTitleChangeListener implements ChangeListener<String> { // Because of that error, I tried this
        private final CharSequence titleBasis;

        MyTitleChangeListener(CharSequence initTitleBasis) {
            titleBasis = initTitleBasis;
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldTitle, String newTitle) {
            String correctedTitle = newTitle == null || newTitle.isEmpty() ? titleBasis : newTitle + " - " + titleBasis;
            // Here is where I don't know what to do.
            // Certainly something with correctedTitle, right?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why try to intercept setTitle?  Why not just write a brand new method called `setCurrentDocumentName` (or something similar) that sets the title intelligently?

Comment: @VGR so I can pass this along to other libraries that don't (and IMO shouldn't) know about this special behavior.

Comment: I am still not able to understand what do you want to achieve here? Do you want to set the title or do you want the user to be able to change the title on his will? Either way, you have already achieved what you want.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I want anything to be able to set the title, but just before it's changed, I want to ensure the app name is there. This works in the Swing example I've provided, but I have no idea how to do it in JavaFX because the `Scene#setTitle(String)` method is `final`.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the `titleProperty()` of the stage to the `textProperty()` of the textField, concat the appname before the binding or just expose it to be used later.

A very simple way to use it is to add :

```
primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(Bindings
                  .concat("My-App").concat(titleTextField.textProperty()));
```

*You can also alter how to use it, deepening on your use case.*

A complete example :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static final String APP_NAME = "My App ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField titleTextField = new TextField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(titleTextField, 1, 1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(APP_NAME).concat(titleTextField.textProperty()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

***EDIT*** - Based on OP's comments

A complete solution based on `MyWindow` in JavaFX.

```
public class MyWindow extends Stage {
    public static final String APP_NAME = "My App";

    public void setupStage(Stage stage) {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        stage.titleProperty().addListener((observable, oldTitle, newTitle) -> {
            if(newTitle == null || newTitle.isEmpty()) {
                setTitle(APP_NAME);
            }
            else if(!newTitle.equals(oldTitle + "-" + APP_NAME) && !newTitle.equals(APP_NAME)) {
                setTitle(newTitle + "-" + APP_NAME);
            }
        });
    }

    public MyWindow() {
        super();
        setupStage(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you abstract this so it will work inside the `MyWindow` class?

Comment: This looks really promising! If you can modify it to work inside my `MyWindow` class, I'll accept it as my answer!

Comment: Your `MyWindow` is a total mess. You don't need the `listener` to `titleProperty()`, neither do you need the `changeListener` called `MyTitleChangeListener`. Since you have the string `APP_NAME` defined in the class, you can just bind it as I have show above.

Comment: I meant, how do I do this in a separate class, without the text field?

Comment: Do you want to set the title through different controls? Do you have a dedicated control for setting the title?

Comment: I want to be able to call `stage.setTitle("foo");` and it automatically sets the window's title to `"foo - My App"`, in the exact same way that my first example code makes it possible in Swing; that's why I provided it

Comment: So, I wish to have this work without controls at all. That is why I removed them from my example code.

Comment: In your example you have hard-coded the app name, where exactly will the app name be coming from. Will you have a `setTitle()` in your custom class?

Comment: In the production, the app name is in a localized XML file and fetched at runtime, then stored in a `final` variable in a globally-accessible utility class. I want my custom class to be usable by anything that only sees it as a generic `Scene`. So, a theoretical `SomeoneElse` class might try to set my window's title, and my window will see this and know to change it appropriately.